Conformal mapping to the unit disc
Consider the region
$$
\Omega = \left\{z:\Re z > 0,\ \Im z \le 0\}\cup\{z:\Im z \in \left(0,1\right)\right\}
$$
I want to find an explicit conformal mapping from $\Omega$ to the unit disc.

I tried
$$
w=\frac{\sqrt{1+\left(z-i\right)^{-2}}}{1+\sqrt{1+\left(z-i\right)^{-2}}}
$$
When we take $\arg(1+(z-i)^{-2})\in(0,2\pi)$ this sends $\Omega$ to
$$
\{x+iy:x>0,y\in(0,f(x))\}\ \mbox{where}\
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=0
$$
and this $f(x)$ is quite complicate.

So I don't know if this way works, or there exists a better way to solve this problem.

Do you want $\Omega$ to be mapped onto the unit disc or into the unit disc?

@Pranay Of course I mean a bijection between the two regions

Then I am confused. I thought a conformal mapping preserves angles. In particular, the boundary of $\Omega$ has a corner at $0$, but there are no such corners on the boundary of a unit circle.

@Pranay Conformal mappings do preserve angles in the region, but may not preserve the angles on its boundary, for example, $w=z^2$ maps the first quadrant to the upper half plane coformally. You could find more details in any textbook on complex analysis

Makes sense, thanks for the example!

I know the answer now. The region $Omega$ should be treated as a "triangle" with angles $0,\frac{3\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{2}$ so that we could apply Schwarz-Christoffel integral to this. Let $\begin{align}f(z)=\frac{1}{\pi i}\int_0^{z}\frac{\sqrt{\zeta}}{1+\zeta}\mathrm{d}\zeta\end{align}$, then one could verify that $f(z)$ is indeed a conformal mapping from upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ to $\Omega$. The desired conformal mapping is clear now.
